# what if bean is not find by name in autowire byName,will it go for property tag else pls define me flow in normal bean wiring or autowiring in XML

Tags: java, autowired

Below is my XML , in which I have made it autowired, but able to get how to make its beans of preperty student as it is in list and this list contains object of student.So can anyone help how to make it autowired="byName"or "byType", else also can any one help with navigation flow in normal bean wiring and autowiring in configuration file.

```
<property name="students">
        <list>
            <ref bean ="Richard"/>
            <ref bean ="Steve"/>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name ="books">
        <set>
            <ref bean ="DBMS"/>
            <ref bean ="Java"/>
        </set>
    </property>



<property name="studentContacts">
    <map>
        <entry key ="23456" value-ref="Richard"/>
        <entry key ="67891" value-ref="Steve"/>
    </map>
</property>

<property name ="faculties">
    <props>
        <prop key="Robert">Computer science</prop>
        <prop key ="Casper">Mechanical</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean name ="Richard" class ="Student">
    <property name ="name" value ="Richard"/>
    <property name = "age" value ="22"/>
    <property name ="department" value ="Computers"/>
</bean>

<bean name = "Steve" class ="Student">
    <property name ="name" value ="Steve"/>
    <property name ="age" value ="23"/>
    <property name ="department" value ="Communications"/>
</bean>

<bean name ="DBMS" class="Books">
    <property name="bookTitle"  value ="Database Management Systems"/>
    <property name ="author" value ="Peter"/>
</bean>

<bean name ="Java"  class ="Books">
    <property name="bookTitle" value ="SCJP 5"/>
    <property name ="author" value ="Kathey sierra"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Beans` should be defined with `id` this is most common approach. Remember also to define in what package you have that `class`.

```
<bean id = "Steve" class ="${package}.StudentStudent">
    <property name ="name" value ="Steve"/>
    <property name ="age" value ="23"/>
    <property name ="department" value ="Communications"/>
</bean>

<bean id ="DBMS" class="${package}.StudentBooks">
    <property name="bookTitle"  value ="Database Management Systems"/>
    <property name ="author" value ="Peter"/>
</bean>

<bean id ="Java"  class ="${package}.StudentBooks">
    <property name="bookTitle" value ="SCJP 5"/>
    <property name ="author" value ="Kathey sierra"/>
</bean>
```

```
<property name ="books">
    <set>
        <ref bean ="DBMS"/>
        <ref bean ="Java"/>
    </set>
</property>
```

remember to inclode proper namespaces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">


<util:list id="myList"  list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <ref bean ="Richard"/>
        <ref bean ="Steve"/>
</util:list>
</beans>
```

Comment: tahnx for replying rafik, but while autowiring  with byName , den it will check that bean name in xml with the property in class file right, so hows id gonna work.. for more clearance i m sending my both class college and student..

Comment: public class College {
 private String collegeName;
 private String establishedYear;
 
 private List<Student> students;
 
 private Map<String, Student> studentContacts;
 
 private Set<Books> books;
 
 private Properties faculties;

Comment: public class Student{private String name;
 private String age;
 private String department;}

Comment: XMl u have leaving above 3  4 linees